# How to install PowerShell 1.0 for Windows 2008 Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

I have installed Windows 2008 server but I could not find out Powershell (Microsoft mentioned in [its web page](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/download.mspx) that this is part of Windows 2008 Server). Anyway, I tried to find it out from Microsoft web page. The package for Windows 2003/XP does not work. Not sure if the Windows VISTA [x86 Vista RTM](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6EF4735-C7DE-46A2-997A-EA58FDFCBA63&displaylang=en) one is the correct one?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Powershell ships with Windows Server 2008, but indeed is not installed by default.

1. Click **Start** and then **Server
   Manager**
2. On the Left Pane select **Features**
   and on the right pane click **Add
   Features**
3. On the list of features that
   appears, check **Windows
   PowerShell**
4. Click **Next** and then **Install**
5. When the Installation is complete,
   Powershell will be under
   **Start->All Programs**

Have Fun!